# Duplicating tables in InnoDB, any risks of using "Create table like" to do that? Size is worrying

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, create-table

I have some issues with a table that's been growing over the years and is now eating up free disk space. It's only containing about 1.5M rows and yet it takes up almost 20GB. I have been deleting unwanted rows a couple of times but since it's InnoDB I couldn't reclaim any free space when doing so.

Anyway, I have been playing around on a devise using the following commands to duplicate a table:

`CREATE TABLE products_new LIKE products;

INSERT INTO products_new SELECT * FROM products;`

So far so good, it took about 200 seconds to perform that one on a dev-site with about 200k rows.

But what's worrying is the size of the new table. It's tiny compared to the original one! Did I miss anything when inserting the data? Sure, I expected to regain some data since I've been deleting rows but not this much.

[size of new table vs old table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp6ht.png)

I have tried this on a couple of tables but only on dev-sites and I'm worried that I have missed anything since the difference in data size is so massive. Is this normal behavior when creating a new InnoDB table with old data?

Worth mentioning that innodb_file_per_table is ON.

Comment: It is probably because the table stats have not been updated since the insert. Try running ANALYZE TABLE and then checking the size again.

Comment: Thank you! That seems to be the case. After performing "analyze table" they are similar in size. Is there any difference in doing this way of copying compared to just use optimize table for reclaiming space?

Comment: What _was_ the value of `innodb_per_table` when you created the _original_ table?  48K says that you have not yet populated the table; did that `INSERT` get any errors?  Please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the table stats have not updated since the insert.

```
ANALYZE TABLE products_new;
```

Read more about [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/analyze-table.html)

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE products;
```

on the original table should reclaim the free space. [Read more](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimize-table.html#optimize-table-innodb-details)